# Token authentication and storage / websocket issues

Tags: encryption, web-application, authentication, appsec, websocket

My application is running an API authentication that uses tokens rather than cookies.

This leads me to ask a few questions :

- What is the most secure way to store the token ?

By using random tokens you eliminate the issue of CSRF attacks but on the other side there are no `Secure` and `HTTPOnly` flags.

I thought of maybe using some kind of trick using the new ECMAScript Harmony `Object.freeze()` and `Object.seal()` features but this seems to be more of a hack than something that would be secure.

- How should I authenticate `WebSocket` clients like `Socket.io` on top of HTTPS ?

Most libraries like `Socket.io`, `ws`, `Sockjs` and `Faye` don't allow to set custom HTTP headers or it's not compatible with the various fallback protocols like Flash sockets.

One possibility would be to send the token as part of the handshake in the URL's query arguments but I don't really like it because it means that :

1) - Tokens will be shown in logs files that log only the URL

2) - I would have to authenticate first during the handshake and then every time I send data which would mean two separate systems.

That's just on top of my head by thinking a little bit about it. There might be some more underlying issues.

- Am I just too paranoid and this option is actually secure ?

I could also implement some kind of asymmetric scheme using a public / private key system, but this seems just to error prone / complicated to be a reliable solution.

My final question is more of a consequence of the questions above :

- Is the trade-off of having random tokens rather than cookies worth it ?

On one side you don't have CSRF attack vulnerabilities but on the other side you have a lot of other cases where the answers (for me at least) doesn't seem to be so clear-cut.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

To store the token:

- For a traditional (non-Ajax) web app you usually store the token in a hidden form field.
- For a single page app you usually store the token in a JavaScript variable and include it in the JSON data with each request.

This approach avoids the token being in the URL, and it works with WebSockets.

Most applications use a cookie as the main session ID, and have a second token which is purely to prevent CSRF. You can ditch the cookie and solely use the token, as you suggest, but doing this is not standard practice, so you should only do it if you're sure you know what you're doing.

As you mention, cookies have an HttpOnly option that is not possible with tokens. Although tokens don't have a secure flag as such, that is less important, as you can adjust your code so the token is only ever sent over SSL.

One other thing to be aware of is you can now prevent CSRF without using tokens, primarily using the [origin header](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-03.html). However, most sites still use tokens.

You can do normal cookie authentication with WebSockets. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169842/websocket-authentication) has some information. I don't know what the CSRF implications of this are.

Comment: I'm talking about tokens that are used like cookie replacements, so no CSRF tokens. I want to not use cookies as it is often a security issue and the solutions that exist like CSRF tokens often have implementation issues. Also hidden form fields  often imply server-side rendering which is not necessarily the case. Also storing the token itself in a variable is an issue since you loose persistence.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek - do you have a specific application in mind, or is this a general question? If there's a specific app, more details would help. If it's a general question, I doubt you will find anything that is better than cookies. You could use HTML 5 web storage, but there's no strong reason to prefer this over cookies. Your thinking that "cookies are often a security issue" is misguided. Anything can be a security issue if done badly. Cookies are ok in principle, you just need to take care to use them correctly.

Comment: Well here's my reasoning (correct me if I'm wrong !): In my opinion as a developer, I can eliminate a whole class of attacks (`CSRF`) easily if I don't use cookies. On top of that if I did want to use cookie, CSRF seems to be hard to implement and error prone. Even big companies like Twitter had issues with their CSRF tokens. At the moment I store tokens in the `localStorage` if the "remember me" option is ticked otherwise I use the `sessionStorage`. I might be completely wrong, but this is just how I feel about the situation as a developer.

Comment: Saying you eliminate CSRF by not using cookies is like saying you eliminate SQL injection by not using a database, cookies are needed to exploit CSRF but they are not the cause of it. In my opinion you should use both cookies and token, because they are 2 different layers of protection. A cookie will make sure your session is valid and a token will make sure the request was intended by the client. By using only a token, IF somehow your implementation is flawed and an attacker somehow gets a valid token, he could do anything. This is not the case if he has the token but not the session

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek - CSRF protection is not particularly difficult to get right. If you can't get it right, I expect you will have other security problems with your app, such as cross-site scripting. Most major websites do have security issues from time to time, just like Twitter. This is why the standard approach is cookies + anti-CSRF tokens.

Comment: Tokens can also authenticate users since they are, like cookies, random strings. I'm also not sure why you're saying that cookies are not the cause of CSRF attacks ? Since the browsers are always sending cookies no matter what you request, by default cookies are the cause. How I see it, tokens were added as a patch to protect apps using cookies. Of course it doesn't prevent my app of having implementation issues but I'm not sure why that would be different than cookies ?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek - I see nothing wrong in principle with using HTML5 storage as you explain. I think most sites avoid it because it's tricky to implement. Of course, if you are an SPA you can implement easily. But it always worries me when someone wants to reject the standard way of doing things because they have another idea that is "more secure". In your case, I would just put the effort into implementing normal CSRF protection correctly.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek - CSRF also applies to some situations without cookies - HTTP basic authentication, SSL client certificates, Integrated Windows authentication, and probably more. I agree that this is something of a design flaw with browsers, and tokens are a workaround not a fix of the root cause, but unfortunately these are the design decisions we have to work with.

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek - paj28 explained perfectly why the cookies are not the cause of CSRF, what I mean is, if your token is compromised you are giving away both the session and your CSRF protection. If you had both and your session cookie was compromised it would be useless without the token, same way the token is useless without a a cookie session. In other words in theory there is nothing wrong with your implementation but it seems to me its easier to get it wrong than doing it the standard way, in short, I can´t see any gain on doing it your way.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but why would the cookie + token combination be less easy to compromise than the token alone ? To access the token you would need access to the `localStorage` which means the attacker can execute JavaScript. Why couldn't he, in the same situation, access the CSRF token in the DOM and make a request with the cookie that will automatically be attached ? The reason I'm doing it this way is to not have any issues with session strings being sent without intent.

Comment: Say you have a XSS vulnerability, this would enable an attacker to execute JS like you say. In this way he can get access to the CSRF token like you mention, but not the cookie as long as its properly protected with the httpOnly flag.

Comment: Why would an attacker performing an XSS need the cookie if he can just make a request to which the target's browser will automatically append the cookie to anyway ?

Comment: I´m sorry, I was not clear enough, I didn´t mean a XSS on your own site, that would of course defeat all CSRF protection. I mean a script executed on another domain, since localstorage is inside the browser it can get your session/csrf token, on the other hand, with the standard approach, you wouldn´t care if another site has XSS if your cookie is safe. I know its a longshot but thats the way I can see to defeat your approach.

Comment: No you wouldn't be able to access the token since the `localStorage` is domain specific like cookies are.